# Is it a good naming convention to name elements in lists list?

Tags: python, variables, naming-conventions

I've ran into many situations such as

```
while(len(somelists) > 0):
    somelist = somelists.pop() # prob not the best example
    ...
```

And this often confuses me while I was reading the code because I missed that s in the end.

Since I have seen this quite often in many languages, I just wonder is this actually a good naming convention or not?

Comment: Feels like Hungarian notation.  What if you change it to a Map or Set?  Do you have to rename the variable?

Comment: naming conventions vary, but typically you'll see camel case like "someList".  I generally tie my names to the types, so if the list is of type "Person" then I would name that peopleList and the Person object that is popped will be named "person".

Comment: Could try `somethingJavaLike` which is what I do, personally. Just long-ish and descriptive names, like `longList` and `tempList` in your example.

Comment: @dckuehn that is mixedCase, not CamelCase.  And CamelCase is prescribed by PEP 8 only for classes, lower_case_with_underscores is for methods/variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `s` is okay, but the `list` is not. Try naming your variables for what they represent, not what their type is. So:

```
while(len(cars) > 0):
    car = cars.pop()
```

Of course, some people manage to avoid the question of `s` altogether. They apply the same advice to the container of cars, so we have:

```
while(len(dealership) > 0):
    car = dealership.pop()
```